# List data from two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, Items and Calibrations. Items has many calibrations, meaning that every year the instruments have to be calibrated. Fields, `date_calibration` and `date_expired`, are located in the "calibrations" table. (Items: has_many :calibrations, calibration: belongs_to item)

I need list/show all the items that are expiring. I can list all the items without problem of course but, I don't know how to add `date_expired` to the list.

In the Items controller:

```
@items = Item.all.order("created_at DESC")
```

In the Index:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.cod %></td>
    <td><%= item.number %></td>
    <td><%= item.den_cont %></td>
    <td><%= item.branch %></td>
    <td><%= item.model %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I'm using Aptana and PostgreSQL version 9.1, Ruby 2.1 and Rails 4.1.
Can anyone of you suggest any solution or point me to the right direction?

UPDATE
What should I change to show the item using the sentence below..

Item_controller
    Item.includes(:calibrations).where('calibrations.date_expired <= ?' , 2014/07/12)

Index
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
Return undefined method each.

ALSO
Any idea on how to show a traffic light depending on how many days left to calibration_date ?? Tks again!

Comment: Do you want to just add 'date_expired' column? or you want to show items whose date_expired is close to X days?

Comment: I need show items whose date_expired is close to.. for example. Warning that left 15 days to calibrate the item.Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long you have your relations properly defined in your models I do believe something similar to the following should do the trick!

```
Item.joins(:calibrations).where(date_expired <whatever condition>)
```

The equivalent SQL being:

```
SELECT          Items.* 
FROM            Items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Calibrations 
ON              Calibrations.item_id = Items.item_id 
WHERE           date_expired <whatever condition>
```

With the equivalent SQL of the above statement being (using the `includes` method):

```
SELECT          * 
FROM            Items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Calibrations 
ON              Calibrations.item_id = Items.item_id 
WHERE           date_expired <whatever condition>
```

Hope this helps!

Also, if you're not wanting to return any data related to the calibrations table (which it looks like this is the case), I would go with the joins method, however if you are, the includes method would be the way to go (http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/)

Also, the following may be of interest: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html (particularly section 12)!

Comment: Thanks Drew, I will do the jobs according to your description and let you know how was it.

Comment: Hi Drew, in may case I have to show date_expire from calibrations table and also show (in some way) a yellow or red flag depending on how many days left to calibrate depending on the date expired.For example if the date expired of the item is 12/12/14 show a red flag warning that is approaching to expired. Also what is wrong with this <% @items.each do |item| %>. Return undefined method each. Tks!! I was testing with Item.includes(:calibrations).where('calibrations.date_expired <= ?' , 2014/07/12)

Answer (score 1):

```
@items = Item.includes(:calibrations)
             .where('calibrations.date_expired <= ?', some_date)
```

`include` will join the two tables and allow you to specify conditions on items based on columns from the calibrations table. I think that's what you wanted isn't it?

Comment: Not sure if you knew this or not, but I do believe the includes method would also return all data from the calibrations table as well!